# urllib3 request time out using inside ThreadPoolExecutor in flask app

Tags: python, flask, redis, threadpool, background-process

I have a python script that works perfectly as a standalone module.

I am trying to use the output of that script in my flask app by initiating that module as a background job using `concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` but unfortunately urllib3 gets failed with the following error only either I use ThreadPoolExecutor or Redis process for background task.

> error with request HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.reddit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/access_token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe8f9490a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 2] Lookup timed out'))

That script is using [praw](https://pypi.org/project/praw/) library that further use urllib3 inside it. Is there any way I can run that module just like it works fine using the main thread?

Comment: Add the list of dependencies that you are using (output of `pip freeze`). Also, if you are using eventlet or gevent, please indicate if you monkey patched the standard library or not.

Comment: Yes, I am doing monkey patching using eventlet during app initialization. The following are lines of code.

eventlet.monkey_patch()

socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', logger=False, message_queue='redis://localhost:6379',
                    engineio_logger=False,
                    cors_allowed_origins="*"
                    )

Comment: @Miguel I have a more clear situation now. If I use eventlet.monkey_patch() in init app then I get the above error I mentioned but I can broadcast using emit but if I remove monkey_patch then urllib3 error goes away and library give me the result but then my broadcast is not working any more. Tried both redis and celery for this background job.

Can you please help me.

Comment: If you are willing to give up websocket, then uninstall eventlet, remove the async_mode argument and remove the monkey patching. That should work fine. Unfortunately some of the things that you are doing are incompatible with eventlet.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you so much. I have done that using the pusher library for the moment but this question is still a mystery for me to overcome this incompatibility.